# Reading in numbers between parentheses

Tags: matlab

I am trying to import numbers between parentheses in Matlab. I am using the software OpenFoam that produces a file that extract velocity's (u,v,w) at a number of different positions for different time steps. I would like to import these velocity so I could take their average over a certain time intervall. I have about 250 probes in my flow domain, meaning I would like to import 750 different numbers for a number of different time steps. The file looks like this:

[image]
Link to file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CuoflLADasUybsR4UJf1PQBUcGD0SsVb/view?usp=sharing

So I would like to import all the numbers in to a matrix with size ((number of time steps) X (probes))

I found a code that does works and imports these numbers, but this is very manual.I would have to write out probexx(i,:) = (str2double(split(out{i,1}{1,xx})))'; manually 250 times to get it to work. I would like to have a more automatic code, so I could change the number of probes easily.  Could any one help me?

Thank you in advance!

```
id = fopen('probe.dat','r');

t = textscan(id,'%s','delimiter',sprintf('\n'));
fclose(id);

out = regexp(t{1,1}(6:end-3), '(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))', 'match', 'all');

probe0 = zeros(size(out,1),3);
probe1 = zeros(size(out,1),3);

for i = 1:size(out,1)
    if ~isempty(out{i,:})
        probe0(i,:) = (str2double(split(out{i,1}{1,1})))';
        probe1(i,:) = (str2double(split(out{i,1}{1,2})))';
    else
        probe0(i,:) = [0,0,0];
        probe1(i,:) = [0,0,0];
    end

end
```

Comment: Why would you have to write this 250 times? Why can't you have another loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this assuming that each row is uniform after the header lines.

```
id = fopen('probes.dat','r');
t = textscan(id,'%f','Delimiter',{'(',')',' '},'MultipleDelimsAsOne',true,'headerlines',5);
fclose(id);

numProbes = 254;
temp = reshape(t{1},numProbes*3+1,[]);

outData.time = temp(1,:).';
for ii = 1:numProbes
    rowIdx = (ii-1)*3+2:(ii-1)*3+4;
    outData.(num2str(ii,'probe%d')) = temp(rowIdx,:).';
end
```

Basically read all of the numeric data into 1 array.  Using the multiple delimiters feature and specifying the number of header lines.  Next reshape based on the number of probes (in your example DAT there was 254).

Then loop over the number of probes to assign it to fields of a structure with the variable names that you want (probeXX).

This leaves you with a structure of the form:

```
outData = 

        time: [47x1 double]
      probe1: [47x3 double]
      probe2: [47x3 double]
      probe3: [47x3 double]
      ...
      probe254: [47x3 double]
```